# PHP Simple loop limit via GET

Tags: php, arrays, loops, get

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Why is my PHP multi dimensional array not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12672475/why-is-my-php-multi-dimensional-array-not-working)

## Updated

I want to be able to add the URL `category.php?filter=Blue and green` or `category.php?filter=Red` and then have my array list to only display colours with those values - otherwise it will list all the array.

```
<?php

$array = array(
"1" => array("red", "black", "blue and green"),
"2" => array("orange"),
"3" => array("silver", "gold"),
"4" => array("pruple"),
"5" => array("pink", "yellow"),
"6" => array("black")
);
# no more more edits, loop begins below
# limit the the rows by 3 and break
$data = array_chunk($array, 3);
/*#######################################
 No more edits DO NOT EDIT FURTHER
#######################################*/?>
<?php
foreach ($array as $data):
?>

<div class="item" id="item_<?= $row ?>">
    <div class="itemdata">
    <?php #foreach ($array as $row): ?>
    <?php foreach ($data as $row): ?>
        <?php if (in_array($row, explode(' and ', $_GET['filter']))): ?>
            Product Link = <?=$row?> 
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endforeach ?>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

I have updated my code according to posts below. So far it only loops two items - without any `filter` applied to the URL

Comment: This `<div class="item" id="item_<?=$row?>">` probably won't do what you expect.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, your array seems not correct :

```
# list of product Ids and their assoc colours
$array = array(
"1" => "red", "black", "blue and green",
"2" => "orange",
"3" => "silver", "gold",
"4" => "pruple",
"5" => "pink", "yellow",
"6" => "black"
);
```

If product 1 has 3 colors, it probably should read :

```
array (
    1 => array("red", "black", "blue"),
    2 => array("orange"),
```

etc.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the array and the loop, and added a filter:

http://codepad.org/YnafFVP4

`array_chunk` breaks your multidimensional array, so you can't use this. If you can explain what you want to limit we could help with that, too.

Comment: The code does not work fully. The second part does not filter fully

Comment: I have updated my answer with this code base but not working fully.

Comment: True, I did some more fixes but I had to remove the limit.

Answer (score 0):

Thats how your array should look like

```
$array = array(
"1" => array("red", "black", "blue and green"),
"2" => "orange",
"3" =>  array("silver", "gold"),
"4" => "pruple",
"5" => " array(pink", "yellow"),
"6" => "black"
);
```

Answer (score 0):

First, your array is not correct.
It must be like:

```
$array = array ("1" => array("red", "black", "blue"),
    //etc
)
```

Second, your foreach seems to be incorrect.

Foreach looks like:

```
foreach($array as $key => $value)
```

or

```
foreach($array as $value)
```

This would lead us to the following:

```
<?php foreach ($array as $data): ?>
    // ...
    <?php foreach ($data as $row): ?>
        <a href="/products/<?=$row?>"><img src="/products/<?=$row?>.jpg" /></a>
    <?php endforeach ?>
    //...
<?php endforeach ?>
```

And your to answer your second Question:

In PHP, you can pass arrays in the url if you add `[]` to your variable name:

```
/?color[]=blue&color[]=green
```

And get it with `$_GET['color[]'];`

And as a general tip: use `{}` blocks instead of `:` and `endforeach`. This way you also do IF ELSE constructs:

```
<?php
    if($a == $b) {

    } else {

    }
?>
```

Comment: Your foreach arguments are still invalid. it's `foreach($array => $data)` you seemed to switch those.

Comment: You must also split the value "blue and green" to "blue", "green". This way it works.
Additionnally, `<div class="item" id="item_<?= $row ?>">` won't work because `$row` is not set at this point of time. You need to compute your filter before showing the HTML.

Comment: Something like this? Could you help? http://pastebin.com/szhA0azc

Comment: Almost. This is my suggestion: http://pastebin.com/MTVX5z3r