# Why is my PHP multi dimensional array not working?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, explode

My multi-dimensional array is working. But I cannot seem to use `explode` or `in_array` to limit the array when calling via `$_GET`

```
<?
$shop = array(
array("red", "black", "blue", "green"),
array("orange"),
array("orange", "black"),
array("pink", "yellow")
);

foreach ($shop as $rowNumber => $row)
{
    echo "<li><b>The row number $rowNumber</b>";
        echo "<ul>";
        foreach ($row as $col) {
            if (in_array($col, explode(' and ', $_GET['filter']))){
                echo "<li>".$col."</li>";
            }
        }
        echo "</ul>";
    echo "</li>";
}

?>
```

If I run the script with `$_GET["filter"]=="black"` it displays all items - it should only display two, example this is wrong: the other rows should not appear:

[image]

should be this instead

[image]

Comment: Just so you know, PHP has a `foreach` loop to iterate specifically over arrays.

Comment: I don't even understand how one would expect this code to work in the first place...

Comment: I am sorry I have updated my code. Hopefully this should help.

Comment: Beginner's error, Ignacio. We all started out like that.

Comment: @LuigiEdlCarno: Beginner's error is concatenating "1" and "2" and expecting 3.

Comment: @LuigiEdlCarno - 198k reputation gives you bollocks to speak and comment to people how you wish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Updated

**Solution 1**

```
   <?
    
    $shop = array(
    array("1", "red", "black", "blue and green"),
    array("2", "orange"),
    array("3", "pink", "yellow", "blue and green")
    );
    
    for ($row = 0; $row < count($shop); $row++)    
     {

            $lis = "";
            for ($col = 0; $col < count($shop[$row]); $col++)
                {
                     if (in_array($shop[$row][$col], explode(' and ', $_GET['filter'])) 
                        || empty($_GET['filter'])){
                        $lis .= "<li>".$col."</li>";
                     }
                }
           if($lis != "") {
             echo "<li><b>The row number $row</b>";
             echo "<ul>";
             echo $lis;
             echo "</ul>";
             echo "</li>";
         }
    }
    
    ?>
```

**Solution 2**

```
<?

$shop = array(
array("1", "red", "black", "blue and green"),
array("2", "orange"),
array("3", "pink", "yellow", "blue and green")
);

for ($row = 0; $row < count($shop); $row++)    
{
    $lis = "";
    
    for ($col = 0; $col < count($shop[$row]); $col++)
    {
            if (in_array($shop[$row][$col], explode(' and ', $_GET['filter']))){
                $lis .= "<li>".$col."</li>";
            }
    }
    
    if($lis=="") {
        
            echo "$row";
        
    } else {
        
            echo $lis;
        
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: See my update above. I want to hide the results if GET is not empty

Comment: @user1686277 - code is updated. I store LIs with colors into temporary variable and echo row number etc only if it is not empty

Comment: I want to display full array if empty. If not empty then show the filter. Your new code shows empty array if no filter

Comment: See latest update. Just check if `$_GET['filter']` is empty. See `|| empty($_GET['filter'])` in `if` statement

Comment: Thanks. I also figured my own solution so I have added both of these. Thank you so much my friend.

Answer (score 0):

Your col-Variable contains a number (1, 2 or 3) But the explode-call returns an Array containing words (green, blue, orange)

Even though PHP could handle the cast from 1 to "1", it can not cast from 1 to "green".

Answer (score 0):

Just Gussing maybe you want to print somthing like this

```
$shop = array(array("1","red","black","blue and green"),array("2","orange"),array("3","pink","yellow","blue and green"));

echo "<ul>";
foreach ( $shop as $info ) {
    $info = array_pad($info, 4, "none");
    list($id, $color1, $color2, $mixed) = $info;
    printf("<li><b>The row number = %d , Color = 1  %s , Color 2 =   %s , Mixed  = %s </b></li>", $id, $color1, $color2, $mixed);
}
echo "</ul>";
```

Output

- **The row number = 1 , Color = 1 red , Color 2 = black , Mixed =
              blue and green**
- **The row number = 2 , Color = 1 orange , Color 2 = none , Mixed =
              none**
- **The row number = 3 , Color = 1 pink , Color 2 = yellow , Mixed =
              blue and green**

Answer (score 0):

I think you can simply do something like this:

```
<?
$shop = array(
array("red", "black", "blue", "green"),
array("orange"),
array("orange", "black"),
array("pink", "yellow")
);

foreach ($shop as $rowNumber => $row)
{
    echo "<li><b>The row number $rowNumber</b>";
    echo "<ul>";
    foreach ($row as $col)
    {
        //Compare both values, if they match, it prints
        if ($col == $_GET['filter'])
        {
             echo "<li>".$col."</li>";
        }
    }
    echo "</ul>";
    echo "</li>";
}

?>
```